# How do I use a custom JsonConverter with NServiceBus?

Tags: json.net, nservicebus

I have a class that needs a custom JsonConverter to properly be deserialized.  It is a value object (in DDD terminology), and I need to include it in a message being sent with NServiceBus when using Json serialization.

The problem is, since NServiceBus internalizes their copy of Json.Net, I have to use the JsonConverter base class that is included in NSB, but it has been marked "internal" during the merge.

This basically prevents you from hooking any custom serialization code into NSB. Is this by design?  Is there a recommended workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are having problems with the merged assemblies you can find the core only assemblies on the [downloads page on github](https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/downloads).

Comment: Off the top of my head, I don't think so, but I would double check.  You could set them up on an internal NuGet server if that is helpful.